# How to deal with HTTP API response with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, httpwebresponse

I am working with some web projects that deal with HTTP API response(s) in following format:

```
{response_header1=value1,response_header2,value2,response_header3=value3,response_header4=,response_header5=value5}
```

Or

```
error xxx,err_desc=Invalid password
```

These responses don't look like a standard `XML` or `JSON` format. I would like to know what's the best way to handle these type of responses in `PHP`.

Comment: Go with regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will handle what you have posted as a standard response from the API you are working with:

```
$var = '{response_header1=value1,response_header2,value2,response_header3=value3,response_header4=,response_header5=value5}';
if(strpos($var, '}') !== false) {
    parse_str(str_replace(',','&',trim($var,'{}')), $var);
    var_export($var);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

If you need to handle the specific error values, you can access and parse them where I have placed the `echo` statement.  What I did, is strip the left and right squiggly braces, then converted the entire string into a standard URL query, which is parsed by the `parse_url` command and stored back as a key=>value set (like accesing $_POST or $_REQUEST vars) in the variable named `$var` -- You can see this result from the `var_export($var)` command.

This is also much faster than `explode`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to write a custom converter with regular expressions or you need to convert it inside your code. Here's an example for inline conversion without regular expression:

```
$incoming = "{response_header1=value1,response_header2=value2,response_header3=value3,response_header4=,response_header5=value5}";
$splitted = explode(",", trim($incoming,'{}'));

$values = array();
foreach($splitted as $split) {
    $exploded = explode("=",$split);
    $values[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1];
}
```